# How to add default content in multiple lines of text

Tags: 2007

I would like to know if in SP2007 there is a way to place a default content in a field Multiple lines of text.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution in javascript but demand through SP designer

I added my code just before the first tag "table" of my file (line 16)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("LoadMe");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// afficher le tableau dans les champs multiligne
function LoadMe()
{
document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_86466505_162d_4029_bbf4_9f1255c17236_ctl00_ctl04_ctl10_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave").value="MY_HTML_CODE_HERE";
document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_86466505_162d_4029_bbf4_9f1255c17236_ctl00_ctl04_ctl11_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave").value="MY_HTML_CODE_HERE";
document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_86466505_162d_4029_bbf4_9f1255c17236_ctl00_ctl04_ctl12_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_spSave").value="MY_HTML_CODE_HERE";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sharepoint site column such as multi_line_test

then create a sharepoint designer workflow that starts on item created
and set multi_line_test to "enter default text"

this will create a new item with a multiline text field to a default value.

Yatindra